# get class name from element with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Because of different reasons I can NOT use $('.class').click or on('click', function..)

So I really have to use the onclick="" event from the html element.

Is there a way to find out the class from the element where the onclick happens?

and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aw8Rb/

Thanks for all the help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<span class="classic one"   onclick="someFunction('one')">CLICK HERE</span>
<span class="classic two"   onclick="someFunction('two')">CLICK HERE</span>
<span class="classic three" onclick="someFunction('three')">CLICK HERE</span>
<span class="classic four"  onclick="someFunction('four')">CLICK HERE</span>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function someFunction(abc) {
        alert(abc);
        alert($(this).attr('class'));

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: toggle solution worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/984471

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you need to pass `this` reference  when calling the function

try this

```
<span class="classic one"   onclick="someFunction(this,'one')">CLICK HERE</span>
......  //same for others
```

**jquery**

```
function someFunction(obj,abc) {
        alert(abc);
        alert($(obj).attr('class'));

    }
```

**with plain javascript (without Jquery)**

```
function someFunction(obj,abc) {
        alert(obj.className);
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw8Rb/4/)

Comment: Thanks! It helped Cheers buddy :)

Comment: It worked but it is fetching internal classes too along with the given class, So is there any way that to get the class name without the internal classes

Comment: @KunalTyagi Sorry for late but you cannot do that since `className` or `.attr('class')` will give you all the classes associated to that element. You can loop through these classes and get/check for the one you required. Bottom line is, it actually depends on what you need after you get the classes, loop through it and do what you need. 
Enjoi coding

Answer (score 5):

A non-jquery way using `this.className` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aR7MF/1/).

Answer (score 2):

If you add the element to the argument you can use it into your function to retrieve all data that you want
Try this:

```
    <span class="classic one"   onclick="someFunction('one',this)">CLICK HERE</span>
    <span class="classic two"   onclick="someFunction('two',this)">CLICK HERE</span>
    <span class="classic three" onclick="someFunction('three',this)">CLICK HERE</span>
    <span class="classic four"  onclick="someFunction('four',this)">CLICK HERE</span>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function someFunction(abc,obj) {
            alert(abc);
            alert($(obj).attr('class'));

        }
    </script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw8Rb/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Pass `this.className` as the parameter .. eg.

```
<input type="button" onclick="abc(this.className)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

From `jsfiddle` you provided, edit your code like below and you'll get answer (class) properly.

```
<span class="classic four"  onclick="someFunction(this,'four')">CLICK HERE</span>

function someFunction(obj,abc) {
    alert(abc);
    alert(obj.getAttribute('class'));   
}
```

Pass `this` as first argument and then access it in function with `obj`. After that you can use `obj.getAttribute('class')`

Answer (score 1):

Add `this` as an argument to the inline event handler:

```
<span class="classic one"   onclick="someFunction(this,'one')">CLICK HERE</span>
```

Then use the `className` property of element to get the className

```
function someFunction(e,abc) {
      console.log(this);
      alert(e.className);
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/Aw8Rb/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="javascript:someFunction(this)"

function someFunction(obj) {  
            console.log($(obj).attr('class'));  
}
```

You will get the two classes in the order of writing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
js...
function thisFunction(e) {
  console.log(e.target.class); // should return the class of the element that called it (button)
}
html...
<button onclick="thisFunction()">Click Me</button>
```