# On Click function with uknown ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write javascript that will will show/hide a paragraph when I click on an arrow.  The catch is, I am generating a list of titles and next to each title is an arrow.  This is generated through a loop on the server.  When its passed the code has no ID.  To solve that, I ran the following javascript to create ID's:

```
var countPosts = document.getElementsByClassName("jobs-article-holder-content-whole-teaser").length;
var myNewID = "article-holder-dropdown-"
for (var i = 0; i < countPosts; i++) {
    myNewID = "article-holder-dropdown-" + (i + 1);
    document.getElementsByClassName("jobs-article-holder-content-whole-teaser")[i].setAttribute("id", myNewID);
}
```

html is

```
loop
        <div class="jobs-article-holder-content-page">
            <div class="jobs-article-holder-content-whole">
                <div class="jobs-article-holder-content-whole-box">
                    <h3>$MenuTitle.RAW</h3>
                    <div class="job-article-holder-click-for-more-link">
                        &#x25B2;
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jobs-article-holder-content-whole-teaser show">
                    <p class="jobs-article-holder-content-whole-teaser-content">$Teaser</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
end loop
```

To give you a visual:  [image]

Now I'm trying to figure out how can I click on an arrow and have the content hide/show if I don't know the ID's.  Any Idea's?

EDIT:

One thing I can't seem to get around is that the arrow is inside one div, where the paragraph is inside another, how do I change the arrow and hide the div, passing (this) can affect only the arrow, how can I go from there to affect the paragraph?

Comment: onclick="functionname(this);" pass it with reserved word 'this'

Comment: ok but what will be the value of this?  how will I know who this is?  If you look, the arrow is in class job-article-holder-click-for-more-link while the paragraph is in another place, passing this doesn't help because I need to switch the arrow and hide the paragraph.

Comment: You don't need to assign any ids at all. Bind a click handler to the container of the list, that tests whether `event.target` has the class of the arrow. If so, use `event.target.parentNode.nextSibling` (or similar DOM navigation) to get to the element you want to hide/show.

Comment: maybe (this) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060971/get-class-name-from-element-with-onclick helps you

Comment: I'm not sure how that can work Gary, neither is the parrent.  You have divs side by side, so .parent() will hide everything, I just want to hide the paragraph.  So if I put onclick on the arrow, <div><div>arrow</div><div>paragraph</div></div> the parent will hide both divs, I need just paragraph to be hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS to control the show/hide of element:

```
.jobs-article-holder-content-whole-teaser.hide {
    display: none;
}

.jobs-article-holder-content-whole-teaser.show {
    display: block;
}
```

And take control of `click` with jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.job-article-holder-click-for-more-link').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('.jobs-article-holder-content-whole')
            .find('.jobs-article-holder-content-whole-teaser')
                .toggleClass('show hide');
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4xenjhz/).

---

If your elements generated by JavaScript, you need event delegation:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.job-article-holder-click-for-more-link', function () {
        $(this).closest('.jobs-article-holder-content-whole')
            .find('.jobs-article-holder-content-whole-teaser')
                .toggleClass('show hide');
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4xenjhz/1/).

Comment: @TJ The OP said that **This is generated through a loop on the server.**, however I've updated my answer to cover that if the elements generated by client.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `<p>` as follows:

```
$(document).on("click",".job-article-holder-click-for-more-link",function(){
  $(this).parent().next().find("p");
}).
```

Comment: is .next() meaning go to the next div?

Comment: `next()` refers the next sibling.

Comment: Pssst...@Bagzli this is the best answer... we were leading you to it, ROX just gave you the finished product. ;)