# How can I give a class as a parameter to function?

Tags: javascript, html

When I give value as a parameter to function,

such like this,

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style rel="stylesheet">
      .A { border: 1px solid red; background-color: white }
    </style>
    <script>
      function clicked(v) {
        console.log(v);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked(value)">
  </body>
</html>
```

It works well.

It shows me v's value.

However, when I give class as a parameter,

such like this,

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style rel="stylesheet">
      .A { border: 1px solid red; background-color: white }
    </style>
    <script>
      function clicked(c) {
        console.log(c);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked(class)">
  </body>
</html>
```

It gives me an error.

I want to make it show the button's class option, "A".

How can I make it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get class name from element with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060971/get-class-name-from-element-with-onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

> `getAttribute()` returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be `null` or `""` (the empty string);

```
onclick="clicked(this.getAttribute('class'))"
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style rel="stylesheet">
      .A { border: 1px solid red; background-color: white }
    </style>
    <script>
      function clicked(c) {
        console.log(c);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked(this.getAttribute('class'))">
  </body>
</html>
```

**OR:** With [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

> `className` gets and sets the value of the `class` attribute of the specified element.

```
onclick="clicked(this.className)"
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style rel="stylesheet">
      .A { border: 1px solid red; background-color: white }
    </style>
    <script>
      function clicked(c) {
        console.log(c);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked(this.className)">
  </body>
</html>
```

**OR:** Even you can pass *this* object so that you can access all the property inside the function as you need:

```
onclick="clicked(this)"
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style rel="stylesheet">
      .A { border: 1px solid red; background-color: white }
    </style>
    <script>
      function clicked(c) {
        console.log(c.className);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked(this)">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for you. Use DOM element className.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style rel="stylesheet">
  .A { border: 1px solid red; background-color: white }
 </style>
 <script>
  function clicked(c) {
   console.log(c);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked(this.className)">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `this` to the function, and then the function will have access to all of the `input` element properties, among which is `className`, but you can also access any other attributes within, without changing the calling mechanism

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style rel="stylesheet">
  .A { border: 1px solid red; background-color: white }
 </style>
 <script>
  function clicked(v) {
   console.log(v.className,v.value,v.type);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" class="A" value="1" onclick="clicked(this)">
</body>
</html>
```